# Can't find a way to improve my PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have 6 tables named storeAPrices, storeBprices etc.,  holding the same columns and indexes as follows:

- item_code (string, primary_key)
- item_name (string, btree index)
- is_whigthed (number : 0|1, betree index)
- item_price (number )

My desire is to join each storePrices table to other by item_code or item_name similarity but "OR" should act as in programming language (check right side only if left is false).

Currently, my query has low performance.

```sql
select 
*
FROM "storeAprices" sap
left JOIN LATERAL (
                        SELECT *  FROM "storeBPrices" sbp  
                        WHERE                       
                    
  similarity(sap.item_name,sbp.item_name) >= 0.45
                        ORDER BY similarity(sap.item_name,sbp.item_name) DESC
                        limit 1
                      ) bp ON case when sap.item_code = bp.item_code then true else sap.item_name % bp.item_name end 
left JOIN LATERAL (
                        select * FROM "storeCPrices" scp                       
                        WHERE                     similarity(sap.item_name,scp.item_name) >= 0.45
                        ORDER BY similarity(sap.item_name,scp.item_name) desc
                        limit 1
                      ) rp ON case when sap.item_code = rp.item_code  then  true else sap.item_name % rp.item_name end
```

This is part of my query and it took too much time to response. My data is not so large (15k items per table)

Also I have another index "is_whigthed" that I'm not sure how to use it. (I don't want set it as variable because I want to get all "is_whigthed" results)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're asking about multiple distinct things. Please narrow your question down to just one sharply focused issue, and with the *minimum* code needed to describe it.  Also, is "whigthed" meant to be "weighted"?

Comment: This community (also from StackOverflow family) might be a better place to ask https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

OR should be faster than using case

```
bp ON sap.item_code = bp.item_code OR sap.item_name % bp.item_name
```

also you can create Trigram index on item_name columns as mentioned in pg_trgm module [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.44.8), since you are using it's % operator for similarity